# How can I solve this problem of incorrect output in console using c

Tags: c, loops, console, user-input

Here is my code

```
int main(void) { 
  char c;
  int i = 0;
  while(i < 10) {
    c = getchar();
    printf("%c\n", c);
    i++;
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

I want to loop 10 times and get the input from the user, actually only one char per time. and print it back to the console. but the problem is in the output

```
a


b


c


d


e
```

I'm looping 10 times but the input only 5 times. can anyone show me what's the problem?

Comment: You're typing 10 characters: 5 letters and 5 newlines.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to consume the new line ('\n') character from **stdin** each time you get input

```
#include <stdio.h>

void flush() {
  int c;
  while((c = getchar()) != '\n');
}

int main(void) { 
  char c;
  int i = 0;
  while(i < 10) {
    c = getchar();
    flush();
    printf("%c\n", c);
    i++;
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is not defined by the language.

Comment: Ok I have edited my answer, to use a custom flush function.

Answer (score 1):

`getchar()` will return the newlines between the letters. You should skip those.

Also, stop if you get end-of-file. You need to change `c` to `int` to check for this properly.

```
int main(void) { 
  int c;
  int i = 0;
  while(i < 10) {
    c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF) {
      break;
    } else if (c != '\n')
      printf("%c\n", c);
      i++;
    }
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I think the user is only entering one character per line. He was just confused by the script also printing the newlines between them.

Answer (score 1):

The output was performed exactly 10 times.

The problem is that the function getchar also reads white space characters as for example the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter.

Instead of getchar use the function scanf like

```
scanf( " %c", &c );
```

Pay attention to the blank before symbols %c. It is required to skip white space characters.

The program can look for example the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;
    char c;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N && scanf( " %c", &c ) == 1; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%c\n", c );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to use `getchar` then you should declare the variable `c` as having the type `int`.

In this case your program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;
    int c;

    int i = 0;
    while ( i < N && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF )
    {
        if ( c != '\n' )
        {
            printf( "%c\n", c );
            i++;
        }
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry I want to use getchar instead of scanf, but thanks anyway

Comment: @Monio1996 See my appended post.

Comment: yes I am trying to make a guess game, so I need only one char per time, your code deals with that saymoinsam thanks.

Comment: @SaymoinSam "He said that he wants only one char per time" - what you wrote does not make sense. The user can enter several characters before pressing Enter. If you are considering only the first character of the sequence it does not mean that you have only one character per time.With the same success you can process separately ecah character of the sequence saying that you are processing one character per time.

Comment: @SaymoinSamAgain your comment does not make any sense. There are not lots of lines. You can process only the first character of the sequence and move to the second character if it is only required.

Comment: @SaymoinSam No, it shows only one character if you will not be required to process other characters.